# Creating an Online Forum app in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Is it possible to create an online forum in Unity? I am planning to develop an app where engineers can share their prototypes by using an augmented reality computing platform called "tango".

Comment: It's possible to create forum in any programming language as long as there is a network API to communicate with the server. You will need to know Sql and php or any server side language.

Comment: I can suggest [firebase](https://firebase.google.com/) . It also has Unity API, in short i could say; firebase can handle your backend. It also host your data and offers free bandwith (monthly limit). You can check pricing for more information.

Answer (score 1):

The fact you are asking about this means you are heading into a massive headache.

First you need a server to store. Second you'd need a backend interface to upload the models. This parts would require some Front-end tech (.NET or Js related) then some backend tech (.NET, php and so on).

This is for uploading model. You can already start on your own using Ftp client to manually upload the models. In order for Unity to use those, they cannot be Fbx since Unity does not have any runtime fbx uploader. So they'd have to be loaded as obj or your own 3d extension along with shader details and texture.
You would sum the model up in a json file containing all the url regarding a single model.
Another solution is to use AssetBundle but that means you have a backend process to convert those as you can't expect all the engineers to use or know Unity and how to create AB.

In Unity, you'd have to first know the url of the data, then download the json file, then parse and read through to get all content and reconstruct the model in Unity.
AB are easier in this case as Unity provides an API.

As for the Tango side, this might be the easiest part if you just use a sample example.

This is highly over-viewed and has no implementation, just high level design. Already, I mentioned at least about 4 different tech to use.

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

[Unity supports SQL](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/?_escaped_fragment_=/content/3845#!/content/3845), so you can code the forum in Unity without an API, but the latter works too.